# Setting autossh tunnels

Tags: linux, autossh

We have server with installed autossh

Number of tunnels approximately 20

Today we add new tunnel, but not work.

If change new tunnel instead previous the a new tunnel works, and previous there is no.

For example

```
-o GatewayPorts .........................................................

-o GatewayPorts .........................................................

-o GatewayPorts .........................................................

-o GatewayPorts=yes -i /home/user/.ssh/user -NL 192.168.0.1:80:5.6.7.8:80 user@server.com
```

work fine

```
-o GatewayPorts=yes -i /home/user/.ssh/user -NL 192.168.0.2:80:1.2.3.4:80 user@servernew.com
```

not work

---

if we change line

```
-o GatewayPorts .........................................................

-o GatewayPorts .........................................................

-o GatewayPorts .........................................................

-o GatewayPorts=yes -i /home/user/.ssh/user -NL 192.168.0.2:80:1.2.3.4:80 user@servernew.com
```

work fine

```
-o GatewayPorts=yes -i /home/user/.ssh/user -NL 192.168.0.1:80:5.6.7.8:80 user@server.com
```

not work

May be exist restriction limit connection?

Comment: I feel like this might find a better audience over at https://unix.stackexchange.com/ since this isn't really "programming" related which is what Stackoverflow is focussed on. There are a lot of smart SSH folks over here though so perhaps it will get some traction.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.